# Openerp/Odoo Scalablity limit

Tags: postgresql, odoo, scalability, performance-testing

How scalable is Odoo with regard to the number of users it can support and still run smoothly?

Also, how many records can it entertain without facing server load issues when many users are using it simultaneously?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your server configuration, disk performance, processor, memory, etc. There are many performance factors not unique to Odoo.

For performance information you must read this: [Odoo Performance](http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/performance2014-35689113?qid=6059c72d-5176-4ef6-9c3c-9da8acce8ef0&v=default&b=&from_search=7)

Odoo has a PostgreSQL database, for better performance you must read about PostgreSQL as well.

Also, see the [Performance Comparisons](http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/odoo-open-source-cms-a-performance-comparision) like speed test, load test, scalability etc.